# Using Custom Renderer in Aggrid cell causes autoSizing of Column width to fail / become non existent

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using a custom Cell renderer for our Aggrid Component, While using the default renderer the auto sizing works fine, but as soon as we move to a custom renderer the auto sizing fails .,

```
{
            headerName: 'Impacted Items',
            cellRenderer: ReactCellRenderer,
            cellRendererParams: {
                Component: Myrenderer
            },
        },
```

**React Cell Renderer**

```
import React, { ComponentType } from "react";
```

import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";

export type ReactCellRendererParams = {
Component: ComponentType;
directToPath: any;
};

export class ReactCellRenderer {
domWrapper: HTMLElement;

```
constructor() {
    this.domWrapper = document.createElement("div");
}

init(params: ReactCellRendererParams): void {
    render(
        <params.Component {...params} />,
        this.domWrapper,
    );
}

getGui(): HTMLElement {
    return this.domWrapper;
}

refresh(params: ReactCellRendererParams): boolean {
    render(
        <params.Component {...params} />,
        this.domWrapper,
    );
    return true;
}

destroy(): void {
    unmountComponentAtNode(this.domWrapper);
}
```

}

Comment: did you figure it out how to make it work?

Comment: Yes i created a custom rendered to be used with react